# Would a Hohmann transfer within LEO be useful?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, hohmann-transfer

Hohmann transfer is often used between a lower LEO orbit and MEO, GTO, GEO or beyond.

But if the target is a high altitude within LEO, how would a direct ascent compare to ascent to a lower orbit followed by a Hohmann transfer to the higher one?

- Would the inclusion of the intra-LEO Hohmann transfer help at all in reducing costs or payload mass?
- Are there other considerations?

Comment: Hi @RajathPai I've adjusted the wording of your question a bit. I think it hasn't changed your meaning, but if you have a moment can you take a look and double-check? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "direct ascent"? A Hohmann transfer in LEO is quick, it just needs 1/2 orbital period, i.e. roughly 1 hour.

Comment: @asdfex a direct ascent means that there is not intermediary parking orbit as is common in the Hohmann transfer.

Comment: You mean like jumping from one orbit to another? There's always an intermediate orbit / trajectory after leaving the original orbit and before entering the new one (unless they intersect at some point)

Comment: @asdfex direct ascent from Earth to LEO-high *versus* ascent to LEO-low followed by a Hohmann from LEO-low 1 to LEO-high.

Comment: @uhoh the question asks about "within LEO", not about starting from Earth.

Comment: @asdfex It asks about both, it's a comparison of two things; different ways to go from Earth to a high LEO orbit. I've made another edit to make that clearer, how does it look now?